# How to post data through API (ExpressJS) (ReactJS)?

Tags: reactjs, api, express, post

So basically I have a login I made that sends post data everytime a user presses the login button

```
sendLogin(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('/users', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.email.value,
        password: this.password.value
      }),
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response
    }).then(function(body) {
      console.log(body);
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={(event) => this.sendLogin(event)} class="asdf">
        <input type="text" placeholder="email" ref={(input) => { this.email = input}}/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" ref={(input) => { this.password = input }}/>
        <input type="submit" placeholder="submit"/>
      </form>
    )
  }
```

And in my express server.js code, I have it setup to console log the data we get

```
app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
    var user = req.body;
    res.end('Success');
    console.log('GOT A REQUEST');
    console.log(user);
})
```

The console.log(user) part isn't working at all, and in the client code the console.log(body); part also doesn't work at all. Any idea on how to fix this up?

EDIT: THEY BOTH COME UP AS UNDEFINED

Also when I changed return response to return response.json it gives me this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0
Promise rejected (async)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The console.log(user) part isn't working at all, and in the client
>   code the console.log(body); part also doesn't work at all. Any idea on
>   how to fix this up?

That's becuase of sequence of execution :

Change this :

```
res.end('Success');
console.log('GOT A REQUEST');
console.log(user);
```

To :

```
console.log('GOT A REQUEST');
console.log(user);
res.end('Success');
```

---

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at
>   position 0 Promise rejected (async)

Reason for this error is `res.end('Success');` , you are sending `String` in response instead of `JSON` , try `res.end({data : logged_in_user_data});`.

> **NOTE :  If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as
>   res.send() and res.json().**

Comment: It still gives me undefined and also Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input and it shows response.json() as the error in the react.js code

Comment: try `res.end({status : 'success'});` from node side

Comment: I tried both that and `res.end({data : logged_in_user_data});` but neither have been working. It keeps saying that return response.json(); is an error in the JS code

Comment: Try to use `res.json({status : 'success'});`

Comment: So res.json({status : 'success'}); works, it comes up in the javascript console on the browser. The problem is on the nodejs console.log(user); still comes up as undefined

Comment: I got it working, I had to use the bodyparser extension for request and then do app.use(bodyParser.json()); which got it working! thank you!!